# Magento 2.1.6 : Remove decimals from product view

Tags: magento2

I managed to remove the decimals .00 from catalog.

But, I'm not able to remove from product view & the checkout

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain more, from where you remove decimals?

Comment: I removed from vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js

Answer (score 2):

Create file and use this code :

**=> From :**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

**=> To :**

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuleName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

this file is defined from `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount`

The price itself is coming from this call:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

If we take a look at the file that this method is created based on the class it's inheriting (`/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/Amount.php`)

Update line no 24

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

To

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer() , 0) ?>
```

You need to override

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js

To

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuelName/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils.js

and change the value of precision on line 38:

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

To

```
var precision = 0,
```

Comment: /vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/Amount.php

Dont have that cose in line 24.  .
class Amount extends Template implements AmountRenderInterface

Comment: Read my updated answer. From 
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml this path. create file on mention path and update this line.

Comment: Done ,Created path and file ,Updated line 24 . Still same .

pp/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuelName/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils.js  doesnt exist .

We have porto theme installed

Comment: In

public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js.   we have only jquery.zoom.min.js

We have porto theme installed

Comment: You need to create it. It's not already generated there.

Comment: Created price-utils.js in 
public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js ,, same :(

Comment: Any more suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: I already tested before upload answer and it's working properly. Please check it something you forgot in code.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell that in /vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/Amount.php 
Line 24. is different

Comment: please first of all, read my answer and then apply changes... I never told that..change line in that file which u mentioned in comment.

Comment: OK , Decimals removed . Thank you for the help.

Comment: please accept and upvote answer. so other user can use this code for solve their questions.